# How to find that the result (BigNumber library) is divided by an odd number?

Tags: c++

I am using the BigNumber library in my program. I have a final result in the calculation and need to check whether this result is divided by an odd number or not. If yes I need to write "0" in the result line.
But I have a message

> no operator "%" matches these operands
>   operand types are BigNumber%int

```
#include "ttmath\ttmath.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace ttmath;

typedef Big<4, 256> BigNum; 

int main()
{
    BigNum k,n,result;
    string s;

    cout << "write k" << endl;
    cin >> k;

    for (n= 1; n<15; n+=1)
         { result= n * 123 * (n + (k + 12)) - (k * 5 - 3);
              if (A %2 !=0)
              cout << "result = 0" ;
               else {

           result.ToString(s, 10, false, 2000, 5);
           cout << "result =" << s<<'\t';
             }
     }
    system("pause>>null");
    return 0;
    system("pause>>null");
}
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation - we don't even know (for sure) which BigNumber library you are using.  It looks like there is no `operator %` in this library, it might be called something else or missing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ttmath.org](https://www.ttmath.org/online_calculator), `%` is allowed, but only between two same types.

So you need

```
BigNum divider;
divider = "2";
....
if (result % divider !=0)
...
```